# While launching aritificial satellite,is orbital plane perpendicular or // to equatorial plane of earth?

Tags: astrophysics

If both system is possible, how do we launch satellites so as to make orbital plane perpendicular or // to equatorial plane of earth?

Comment: Polar orbits; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_orbit    Non-inclined orbit; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inclined_orbit

Answer (score 0):

Launching a rocket from a launch site near the equator in an easterly direction maximises the use of the earth's rotational speed, and so reduces the energy/fuel needed to reach an orbit at a given height - the advantage gained can be as much as $460$ metres per second. However, some satellites used for earth mapping or observation need to cover more of the earth's surface than a [near-equatorial orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-equatorial_orbit) would allow. These satellites will be launched into a polar orbit, so that they can cover most of the earth's surface as it rotates beneath them.

Comment: In launching for a polar orbit, one might launch in a direction somewhat west of north (or south) to compensate for the rotation of the earth.